# How to put a ".setChecked" with a boolean?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a problem with my `MainActivity`, I try to put the function setchecked() with my `boolean`, that is a `CheckBox` . But I do not know how to do it. Can you help me ?

A part for `MainActivity` :

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();  
    SharedPreferences myPreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 

    if(myPreference.getBoolean("checkBoxValide", false)){
        //myPreference.getBoolean("checkBoxValide").setChecked Hum...                                   
    }else{
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LicenseValide.class);
        startActivity(intent5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you wants to set checkbox box value to SP ? or SP value to checkbox

Comment: Your preference itself is not a `CheckBox`. Do you have a `CheckBox`  View defined in your layout that you want to use here?

Comment: I want to set checkbox box in default value.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get a reference to your `CheckBox`. This is similar to getting a reference to any other View:

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox_id);
```

You can then call `myCheckBox.setChecked(true);` to change it to the "checked" state.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my checkbox is in another Activity. So, how use "findViewbyId" because I have a error "checkBoxValide can not be resolved or is not a field" in Eclipse. Sorry for english... .

Comment: If your checkbox is in another Activity, why not set the checkbox's state in that Activity? Your `SharedPreferences` are available from all of your application's components.

Comment: Because I must move the fonction "setchecked" in another activity for exemple , when I button is clicked in another activity.

Comment: What I would do is set the value of your SharedPreference in the Activity with the button, then retrieve the value and set the checked state of your CheckBox in the Activity with the CheckBox.

Comment: Sorry all , I have forget, It's checkboxpreference... .

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();  
    SharedPreferences myPreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 

    if(myPreference.getBoolean("checkBoxValide", false)){
        // R.id.your_checkbox_id is the id you gave to your checkbox in your xml
        CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id); 
        myCheckBox.setChecked(myPreference.getBoolean("checkBoxValide"));                                  
    }else{
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LicenseValide.class);
        startActivity(intent5);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In the activity that has the checkbox, get a reference to myPreference like you do above, and a reference to the checkBox using findViewById() to store the checked state in preferences.

```
// Activity containing the checkbox, put the code either in onPause(), onStop() or 
// toggle state listener
CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);
myPreference.edit().putBoolean("checkBoxValide", myCheckBox.isChecked());
```

Comment: Thank you for you help also, but I said in the previous review : "Because I must move the fonction "setchecked" in another activity for exemple , when I button is clicked in another activity." .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change preference's value to `true`, you should edit property like this.

```
myPreference.edit().putBoolean("checkBoxValide", true).commit();
```

If you want to call `CheckBoxPreference.setChecked()` method, you should do the following inside your preferences activity.

```
CheckBoxPreference checkboxPerf = 
        (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkBoxValide");
checkboxPerf.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Excuse me, I still do not understand how to "import" the checkbox with "findById" Because I based my mistake checkbox does not exist in short, my activity can't find this checkbox. I'm really a "noob" but it could bring alot to me and I'll be very grateful.